# How do you rate limit / throttle a Strapi API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, strapi, throttling

My organization uses a pretty basic strapi API in nodejs, deployed on Heroku. We've been searching for a way to rate limit it to no avail, as it seems heroku doesn't have throttling add ons & strapi doesn't have native throttling capabilities (nor guides).

Has anyone faced this issue before that might have a solution?

Comment: 37.2 seconds after I searched on google, https://forum.strapi.io/t/how-to-setup-rate-limit-for-api/4192/3 suggests that adding rate limiting to strapi is quite straight forward

Comment: 1.- I did it as mentioned in that answer, but the problem is that it has up to 10 requests per minute by default.
2.- It can be done custom, I did several tests but it did not give me results, it always sends me an error 

Answer (score 1):

```
// path: ./config/plugins.js

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  'users-permissions': {
    config: {
      ratelimit: {
        interval: 60000,
        max: 100000
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What "units" do these numbers have? Is it 60000 seconds, milliseconds, ...? I expect it's 60 seconds?

Comment: milisecconds
https://forum.strapi.io/t/how-to-change-ratelimit-in-strapi-v4/19871

Comment: For Strapi v3, remove the "config" key.  Should be just 'user-permissions': { ratelimit: {...}}